# Get Outlook to Send Audio to Laptop Outlook when Headset is plugged in

Tags: audio, microsoft-outlook

A user has a headset connected to their laptop, but they do not want to constantly wear it. Outlook makes a sound when an email arrives that they would like to hear.

You can change the audio Outputs to do this in App Volume and Device Preferences, but Outlook is not listed here. How can we get Outlook to show up here or otherwise use the laptop Audio to announce that an email came in?

Comment: Have not found a solution to make Outlook showing there as well. A similar thread for you to reference:https://superuser.com/questions/258969/routing-applications-sound-to-different-sound-device-windows

Answer (score 0):

Outlook *does* send an audio signal when mail arrives. I assume you have this set in Outlook. It is configured in Control Panel, Sounds.

But you must ask your user to unplug the headset when not using it. Outlook does not know the user is not wearing their headset.

I must deal with the same issue with my iPhone so I am speaking from some experience.